# Joining tables based on value

Tags: sql

I'm having some hard time doing the join function on those two tables. I have simplified the example dataset as there are additional where-clauses involved for the first table however that doesn't seem to be a problem.

I would write the query for joining the two tables below:

```
select a.prod_code, a.prod_name, b.ref_value from Product_code a
left join Product_reference b on a.prod_code = b.pref_code
where a.prod_code <> 'CURTAIN' and b.ref_value = 'MAN'
```

The problem I'm facing is that I want to join tables kind of conditionally. I.e. if the ref_type value is 'MAN' in Product_reference table, I do want to join it, otherwise not.

For an example this query would not include "Chair" in the result as it does not have an ref_type 'MAN' available in the "Product_name". What I'd need though is still show it in the query result, just without joined value from the Product_reference table (given that value with ref_type 'MAN' does not exist for it), not leave it out altogether.

Meanwhile Product_name table record 'CURTAIN' should be left off (regardless if Product_reference ref_type 'MAN' exists or not)

Any recommendations?

```
Product_code    
prod_code   prod_name

A           Table
B           Chair
C           Window
D           Door
E           Curtain


Product_reference       
pref_code   ref_type    ref_value

A           MAN         x
A           AUTO        y
B           AUTO        z
C           AUTO        z1
C           MAN         x1
D           AUTO        zxc
E           AUTO        abc
E           MAN         cba
```

Comment: does this help?, select a.prod_code, a.prod_name, b.ref_value from Product_code a
left join Product_reference b on a.prod_code = b.pref_code
where a.prod_name <> 'CURTAIN' and b.ref_type = 'MAN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `b.ref_value = 'MAN'` to the join predicate:

```
SELECT a.prod_code, a.prod_name, b.ref_value 
FROM Product_code a
LEFT JOIN Product_reference b ON a.prod_code = b.pref_code AND b.ref_value = 'MAN'
WHERE a.prod_code <> 'CURTAIN'
```

This will accomplish what you want, which is only left joining the data from table b where `b.ref_value = 'MAN'`, instead of removing all other rows from the result set altogether.

Side note, thanks for including your query and sample data in your very well made question.  We appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a inner join on  the distinct product that have 'MAN'

```
select 
  a.prod_code
  , a.prod_name
  , b.ref_value 
from Product_code a
inner join (
    select distinct pref_code 
    from Product_reference 
    where ref_type = 'MAN')  t2 on t2.pref_code = a.prod_code 
      and a.prod_code <> 'CURTAIN'
```